# java swing button can change panel into a text area of same size?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jtextarea

Like if we have an gui interface like

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class login1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JTextField username = new JTextField(15);
JTextField password = new JTextField(15);
JButton login1 = new JButton("login1");
JLabel status = new JLabel("Status:Not logged in");
public login1(){
super("login1:");
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(500,500);
GridBagLayout g = new GridBagLayout();
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
setLayout(g);
c.gridx = 0;
   c.gridy =  0;
   add(username,c);
   c.gridx = 0;
   c.gridy = 1;
   add(password,c);
       c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
       add(login1,c);
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 3;
        add(status,c);
      login1.addActionListener(this);
     setVisible(true);
      }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if(e.getSource() == login1){
          String user = username.getText();
           String pass = password.getText();

                           }
              }
             public static void main(String[] args){
            login1 l = new login1();
              }
          }
```

can we direct the input with a button to the same space of panel with a jtextarea like 
the panel was in frame of 500,500 now after entering the details and submitting it using a button can we have the output on the same place with 500,500 JTextArea, with jscrolllpane

Comment: Finish your question, please.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are saying, but many things are possible with java so I am sure you can do whatever it is your asking...but I am assuming you do not just want a yes/no answer... so if you do need help with a certain spot in your code, post it and we can help...if you clear up your question

Comment: Are you asking 1) how to size a `JTextArea` to 500x500 pixels? 2) how to replace your login screen with a `JTextArea` sized to the same dimensions? 3) something else?

Comment: i want to replace my login screen with Jtextarea which is having the user name and password...entered and submitted using the button (sorry i have not included any jtextarea component).

Comment: Use CardLayout and. Place both panel and text area in a container and swap them as needed.